# load css,jquery once for all website pages

Tags: ajax, loading, pagespeed

In my country internet speed is very low thus web developers are sharp in minimizing sent data through http.
I have website with same files in all pages such as css,jquery,javascript,... I need to load those files once for all pages. I use ajax in form submitation and other actions but when a page going to redirect speed is very low.
I think to use ajax in page navigation but there is a problem with ajax loaded javascripts in all pages.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want this: http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Also, follow these best practices to speed up your site: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html

Comment: Are you from China? Does your country block Google?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting on apache, you could place .htaccess file in your webroot, which sets the expiration date to far future values. The disadvantage is, that you need to use version control if you change your JS or CSS.

This is .htaccess content:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Your CSS and JS could be linked like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/jquery.1.7.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="scripts/css/styles-2011-11-03.css" />
```

Everytime you make changes to your CSS or jquery version update the filename.

If you would like to speed up your whole site alot, take a look at the great [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and download Firefox/Chrome Plugins yslow and google pagespeed (if you have access to that).

Comment: The problem with using ...?v=1.7.0 is that proxy caches won't be able to cache the js/css file - the version numbers need to be in the URL not the query string.